# CSS position layer on top - margin & padding, overflow issues

Tags: css

Edit: PROBLEM SOLVED ..

I placed the red_are div within the content_box and for height, I am getting it through jquery and then setting its position as margin-top:-(red_area HEIGHT + content_nox PADDING)px; ..

.. still if anyone has a better idea, please share..

---

I am trying to make a content container, in which I will have an icon or Text on top in the RED div (in code), the problem is the RED div overflows on the next DIV, what I want is that the "content_box" should automatically go down depending on the height of RED div. The second problem is  position of RED div, currently I have set margin-bottom:-50px; but what I want is, it automatically calculates the height and position it in the middle (vertically) over the top line (border).. Below is my code and try.. thanks for your help..

Below is what I want to achieve..
[image]

Reference : http://jsfiddle.net/Dvej8/

Code:

```
  <div class="cb_container">
    <div class="red_area">          
       text <br />
       text <br />
       text <br />
       text <br />
       text <br />
       text <br />
       text <br />
       text <br />
    </div>
    <div class="content_box">
      <h3>Title of Container</h3>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: the answer below gets rid of the red overlapping the content_box.  What do you mean by the second part of the question (centering it vertically)?  Do you want to place the red box on top of the content_box so that the top border of content_box runs directly through the center of red box?

Comment: Thanks Irvin, I just added image to make my question more clear of what I exactly want.. thanks again..

Comment: awesome, that picture really helps.  any particular constraints on this?  in particular, these three questions: may I move around parts of the DOM?  or is the height of the red_area fixed?  is javascript allowed?

Comment: Thanks Irvin, in a perfect world, I should have done without jQuery.. but I think I cant do it only with CSS. the height of red area is not defined, it can be anything of any size, so for position, I can do it like margin-top: -(height of RED + content_box Padding)px; or may be if there is a CSS way of doing it with display:table; and aligning it vertically..

Comment: agreed, though I feel that there are more clever ways to deal with this.  Will let you know if I find a pure CSS solution! :)

Comment: If you've solved the issue yourself and the accepted answer doesn't give everything, you can post your own answer -- unlike other places, here we prefer if questions don't include "problem solved". Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here is a CSS3-only solution that does not require any JQuery (tested on Chrome, Safari and Firefox) and responds to variable heights of red_area that I'd like to share.

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/XP39w/2/)

The main issue with a CSS-only solution is that percentage-based calculations are based on an object's height (for example, margin-top: 50% adds spacing equal to 50% of the width, never height).  Another issue is that the content_box needs to recognize the height of the red_area as well, which may seem impossible without JQuery.

### This solution uses two tricks to overcome these obstacles:

1. Transform's translateY() (CSS3) can move a div *relative to its height*.
2. Two div's positioned next to each other (without margins) appear to be a single div, even with a border (with the right adjustments)

### Relevant CSS:

```
.content_box {
    padding:25px;
    border-right:1px SOLID #e4e4e4;
    border-bottom:1px SOLID #e4e4e4;
    border-left:1px SOLID #e4e4e4;
    border-radius:2px;
}
.red_area_container {
    border-right:1px SOLID #e4e4e4;
    border-top:1px SOLID #e4e4e4;
    border-left:1px SOLID #e4e4e4;
    height:50%;
    transform: translateY(50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
}
.red_area {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    background:red;
    width:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

We wrap the red_area with a div.  We then translate red_area 50% of its height upwards to center it with the top border.  We then translate red_area_container 50% downwards to account for the extra space created by red_area.  The result looks like one div because of how we set our borders.  Try adding/removing content in red_area -- this solution handles that!

Was kinda fun thinking up of this solution :)

Comment: one word : AWESOME..

This is a PERFECT solution, THANK YOU so much, I knew its hard to accomplish, but can be done with css only, my css knowledge is limited :) THANKS A MILLION and am sure, many people will love this.. thanks again mate..

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, you want to do this:

**http://jsfiddle.net/Dvej8/2/**

Correct?

I removed the `margin-bottom: -50px` in `.red_area`. That was the problem. `Margin: 0 auto;` is enough to position it in the middle.

Edit: added `padding` to the top of the container and set the *margin-bottom* back. May I ask why you want that? I am interested. Anyhow, this is how it gets than:

**http://jsfiddle.net/Dvej8/4/**

Comment: thanks again, but there is no change in version 2 and 3.. I want it because that part of my design.. cheers

Comment: I forgot to set the correct link, that's why. Check again. Alright man, thanks for clarification.

Comment: :) I dont want to add padding to content_box I just want it to float automatically if possible..

Comment: What do you mean with float automatically? You can't get that with float. That's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="cb_container">
    <div class="red_area">
        <ol>
            <li>
                <p>text</p>
           </li>
           <li>
               <p>text</p>
           </li>
            <li>
               <p>text</p>
           </li>
            <li>
               <p>text</p>
           </li>
            <li>
               <p>text</p>
           </li>
       </ol>
   </div>
   <div class="content_box">
       <p>More text within here blah blah</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
p,h3{margin:0px;padding:2px;}
.cb_container{
    width:400px;
}
.red_area{
    background:#FF0000;
    width:70%;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
    top:50px;
}
.red_area>ol{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.content_box{
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding:50px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I have sorted it out in a different way and for height of RED area I am using jQuery and then set the position.. cheers

Comment: @user1718343 that's a bit of a long way round :p. It's best to use CSS as much as possible (seeing as it's possible) because unnecessary javascipt can slow down your page. Depends how large the page will be and what's this is for

Comment: thanks Bento.. the problem is in the RED div there can be any kind of content, images, text, <ol> so middling vertically certing cannot be done by fixing it like you added top:50px; or adding 50px to content_box, this is a fixed solution, I will have stuff loaded dynamically and not knowing the height of red area.. for example if I change the text in red area in your example, this is how it looks.. http://jsfiddle.net/5xve3/

Comment: @user1718343 ahhhh I see! Yes then javscript will be needed to change the height.